# Does this iterative process always reach $1$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

This is an iterative process I thought of:

Start with any integer $n$. If $n$ is prime, then divide it by $3$ and round it. If it’s not prime, add $1$.

For example, for $n = 27$, we would add 1:

$27 \implies 28$

28 is still composite, so let’s add 1:

$27 \implies 28 \implies 29$

Now 29 is prime, so we divide:

$[\frac{29}{3}] = 10$

Hence,

$27 \implies 28 \implies 29 \implies 10$.

If you’d like it in a more formal notation:

$$
\begin{cases}
n + 1 & \text{if } n \neq \text{prime} \\
[\frac{n}{3}] & \text{if } n = \text{prime}
\end{cases}
$$

---

My claim is that this reaches 1 for all integers.

This is the sequence of $27$:

$27 \implies 28 \implies 29 \implies 10 \implies 11 \implies 4 \implies 5 \implies 2 \implies 1$

This is the sequence for 100:

$ 100 \implies 101 \implies 34 \implies 35 \implies 36 \implies 37 \implies 12 \implies 13 \implies 4 \implies 5 \implies 2 \implies 1$

We could even construct a directed graph here.

I would think that the sequences generally have a downward trend, but maybe that’s because of the distribution of primes. I think this would reach 1 slower and slower for larger $n$ as the density of primes decreases.

---

Yes, I was inspired by [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Collatz_conjecture).

If anyone can find a quick counterexample it is appreciated.

It is also appreciated if anyone can provide any other information related to this iterative process.

**Edit**: I just didn’t know about Bertrand’s postulate yet. It is easy with the postulate.

Answer (score 6):

Very simplified answer: Because of [Bertrand's postulate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bertrand%27s_postulate), we know that somewhere between $n$ and $2n$ there is a prime. So when you do find your first prime, you will divide by $3$, and thus end up at at most $\frac{2n}{3}$. So no matter where you start, the division will take you lower than your starting point. If you now consider this your new starting point, we see that we must necessarily go further and further down.

I have skipped details regarding what happens for the smallest starting points (say $n<4$) and if we're being completely strict here, you could conceivably end up at $\left\lceil \frac{2n}3\right\rceil$ rather than below $\frac{2n}3$ after finding your first prime. But these are minor issues that don't matter for larger numbers, as the main point is that you end up strictly below $n$ itself, and any case below, say, $n = 10$ can easily be checked by hand rather than through this theory.

Answer (score 0):

This follows directly from Bertrand's postulate; for any integer $n>3$ there is a prime number $p$ such that $n<p<2n$.